# Forming List Comprehension For Dictionary Inside a List of Dictionaries

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a webservice json response which is a list of dictionaries and the values are themselves dictionaries. Like the example below:

```
[
 {
   "ET": {
          "application_environment": "Y",
          "period_process": "Y",
          "extended_options": "N",
          "reports": "Y",
          "administration_tasks": "N",
          "daily_process": "Y",
          "inquiry": "Y"
          }
 },
 {
   "SD": {
           "daily_process": "Y",
           "authorize_cashier_to_close_warranty": "Y",
           "authorize_to_update_technicians_cost": "Y",
           "authorize_to_booking": "Y",
           "authorize_to_policy_adjustments": "Y",
           "authorize_to_pre-paid_maintenance_packages": "Y",
           "authorize_to_enter_actual_time": "Y"
          }
  }
]
```

I have the following which works, I am just wondering if there is a way to do this with list comprehension?

```
    parsed_response = response.json()
    from_svc = []
    for items in parsed_response:
        for values in items.values():
            for daily_process in values.get("daily_process"):
                from_svc.append(daily_process)
```

Comment: d[0]['ET']['daily_process']

Comment: @JustinDanielson what if I want to get a  list of all of the `daily_process` values?

Comment: I have to go for a bit, but I will respond when I'm back. You need to create a list of lists of key-value pairs and then iterate that.

Comment: @JustinDanielson Thanks Justin, I found a way to do this with for loops is as shown above, how do I quash that into list comprehension and is it even worth it to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for?

```
[ values['daily_process'] for items in parsed_response 
                              for values in items.values() ]
```

Comment: Yep, that is what I was looking for, thank you very much.